# Is there any performance improvement migrating from a Hobby dyno to a unique Standard-1X dyno on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Apparently both have the same hardware specs. "Faster builds" and "Preboot" features (available on Standard dynos only) seem to only have impact on deploys.

As for general performance, is it correct to assume both Hobby and Standard-1X dynos will perform equally or am I missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just received an official position from Heroku support:

*"As far as runtime goes the 1X, Free, Hobby and Standard-1X dynos are identical. They have the same RAM, vCPU and ulimit restrictions."*

Comment: This is still the case today (Oct 2017), as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types

Comment: I think the pricing is ridiculous for what you get. 25$ for 512MB memory, in 2018?

Comment: I have a live app:  www.schoolsparrow.com and a staging app:  www.staging.schoolsparrow.com.  Everything is identical with these two apps except staging is on the hobby tier, the main site is on the Standard-1X pro dyno.  If you try conducting a search like this:  chicagoland, 3+ BD, $100,000 max price, 3rd Grade, and select all counties, the staging app throws a timeout.  The same query is fast in production.  Unless there is something I can't see, the Standard-1X dyno allows for much quicker database calls.

Comment: @tomb Databases run as separate add-ons so should not be affected by this. Did you ever confirm your theory?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [limits](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits) and the [Dyno types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos).

The major differences—besides the faster builds & preboot features—are:

- Metrics (the big one, IMO) - the hobby dyno doesn't get this
- You can't have more than one (1) Hobby dyno - [see here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#scalability)

Hope that's clear.

Comment: So both hobby and standard-1x have the same amount of memory (512MB), same "memory behavior" and same "process/threads limits". Putting aside metrics, option to scale horizontally and features that only affect deploys, I assume that **from a user's perspective** it is reasonable to expect about the same performance for a deployed application running on a single standard-1x as on a hobby dyno. Is that correct?

Comment: As far as I can tell (as someone who uses Heroku too): yes.